# Normal/Standard way to compare prevProps in componentDidUpdate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-state

This has come about because during prototyping, I'm finding that incoming new prop(s) might be an array of complex objects, so `prevProps.myProp===this.props.myProp` is always `false`. `JSON.stringify`ing them both before comparison works, but feels unreliable.

I'm trying to write a reusable function for Class Components that compares prev/new props in react's `componentDidUpdate`. For example:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    // First, get difference here, possibly using a lib like npm 'deep-object-diff'.
    // ...or just JSON.stringify both and do string comparison
    const changes = getTheDifference(prevProps, this.props)

    // Don't do anything if there's no changes.
    if (!changes) return

    // Then I want to do something like:
    this.setState( Object.assign(this.state, changes) )
}
```

...that would mean any time the incoming props change, those get immediately reflected in state. I'm having some issues finding a suitable diff lib, but I still feel like I shouldn't be having to do this and am missing something - is there a generally accepted "normal" way to do this, or is me having this problem just a sign of:

- The component is trying to do too much/state too complex?
- I should be mapping props to state with something like Redux? (trying to avoid this until absolutely necessary)
- I'm overthinking it, sometimes the logic in a component's componentDidUpdate is just complex and unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> that would mean any time the incoming props change, those get immediately reflected in state

Yes, that's wrong. When I first started out I was doing the same thing.

1. `state` is something "owned" by that component (noteworthy: not all components need state at all!).
2. `props` are something that are "owned" by a higher component.

Best example:

ComponentA passed an id to ComponentB as a prop. ComponentB uses that id to make an API request (for example).

The status/results of that API request form part of ComponentB's state (it's "owned" by your component). The id passed in as a prop is NOT part of ComponentB's state (it's owned by ComponentA, or maybe somewhere higher in the tree that passed it as a prop to ComponentA).

When the id prop changes, ComponentB will need to make another API request.

EDIT:

The complexity of lifecycle methods is why React has highly encouraged functional components.

You should think of components as functions. It's a lot easier to write the logic if you just think of it as input -> output.

`componentDidUpdate` has been moved to `useEffect` with a dependency list so you can say - run this function, but only when this prop changes - which is a nice way to break down massive `componentDidUpdate` methods into tiny readbale/testable chunks.

I've heard a lot of people say hooks ruined react, but I highly disagree with them. React saw the problems people were running into in the community by misusing class/instance based components and instead of lecturing about how to use them correctly, they nudged people to writing better components by introucing a simpler API - functions, while they still can and will be abused - are generally simpler to deal with than classes and align nicely with composition over inheritance and declarative over imperative.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful! I am definitely finding that I use Class Components by default when I can see now they should be Function Components first and then Class when there's a good reason. I was having to do a LOAD of checks unnecessarily. For anyone else that comes across this, this was a useful article about Functional Components: https://programmingwithmosh.com/react/react-functional-components/